# extract subset of file using five columns

Tags: awk

I have 2 files , one that a biiiiig file (have 249430 rows)
and other is smaller than the first (500 rows)

the first file has this five columns and other columns (the first five columns same in the second file )
such as

```
#CHROM     POS         ID          REF      ALT     QUAL    INFO 
chr2       32424454        rs4576493      T       G       pass    ......
chr8       35578788        rs3686678      C       A        pass .........
chr8       35578788        rs3686678      C       CCG      pass .........
chrx       35578788        rs3686678      C       CCG      pass .........
```

in the second file there are 5 columns such as:

```
#CHROM     POS         ID          REF      ALT
chr2       32424454        rs4576493      T       G
chr8       35578788        rs3686678      C       CCG
```

I want to compare the second file with the first file in each five columns then save only intersection rows between files (but have all columns in the file 1)

So the final file that I want like this

```
#CHROM     POS         ID          REF      ALT     QUAL    INFO 
chr2       32424454        rs4576493      T       G       pass    ......
chr8       35578788        rs3686678      C       CCG      pass .........
```

how can I do it please in unix?
thanks

Comment: `grep -F -f file2 file1`?

Comment: @Cyrus that would match `chr2       32424454        rs4576493      T       C` with `chr2       32424454        rs4576493      T       CCG` , etc. Using `grep` instead of `awk`  for these kinds of things almost always works for some sample input and then fails later on the real input.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
    { key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 }
    NR==FNR { a[key]; next }
    key in a
' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both files are TSV files, i.e., tab-delimited, you may use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`; a tool specifically developed for processing structured data) to perform a relational INNER JOIN operation between the two data sets using the five fields that you mentioned:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv join -f firstfile -j '#CHROM,POS,ID,REF,ALT' secondfile
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    INFO
chr2    32424454        rs4576493       T       G       pass    ......
chr8    35578788        rs3686678       C       CCG     pass    .........
```

Is your data using multiple spaces in place of single tabs, use `--pprint` in place of `--tsv` to signal that you want both input and output to be "pretty-printed".  Use `--p2t` (or `--ipprint` and `--otsv`) to read the input as "pretty-printed" format but to write the output as TSV.